# Def and Return Function in python

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with the def and return function in Python.
On the top of my program I've defined:

```
from subprogram import subprogram
```

then I've defined the def in which I've included the values I wanted to be returned:

```
def subprogram(ssh, x_off, y_off, data_array, i, j):
    if j==1:
        print('shutdonw X')
        # Run command.
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(x_off)
        var_colonna_1 = data_array[i][j]
        return var_colonna_1
        print(var_colonna_1)
    
    if j==2:
        print('shutdown Y')
        # Run command.
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(y_off)
        var_colonna_2 = data_array[i][j]
        return var_colonna_2
```

this is then called in the main program as:

```
for j in range(5, lunghezza_colonna):
  if data_array[i][j] == 'V':
      subprogram(ssh, x_off, y_off, data_array, i, j)
print(var_colonna_1)
```

I was expecting that every time the `subprogram` is called, it returns the `var_colonna_1` or `var_colonna_2`,  but the values I see when I print `var_colonna_1` is always 0 even if, internally the other commands are execute (so X and Y are set in shut down).
Can you help me? I don't see my coding mistake.

Comment: You never do anything with the value you return, I'm guessing you're looking for `var_colonna_1 = subprogram(...`

Comment: well I'm looking for both var_colonna_1 and var_colonna_2 but they have different values inside the if statement.

Comment: The `var_colonna_1` inside your function is not the same one as the one in your bottom snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function doesn't return the variable, only the value on it.

If you want to get the returned value on var_colonna_1, you should asign it, as Sayse said, you should do:

```
var_colonna_1 = subprogram(ssh, x_off, y_off, data_array, i, j)
```